# JSfiddle number guessing game

Tags: numbers, game-physics

I have put together a number guessing game in Jsfiddle, im having trouble getting the random number stored into an array. i need to program to pic a random number and store it untill the number is either guessed or the game ends

here is my fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/e64gt4sv/ 
any help would be appreciated thanks

HTML code:

```
<h1>The Guesssing Game</h1> Pick a number between 1 and 1000:
<input id="myAssumption" type="text" />
<input type="submit" id="byBtn" onclick="checkMyAnswer()" value="Click To See If your Correct" />
```

Js code:

```
    var numberOfSteps = 1;

function checkMyAnswer() {
  var actual = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
    var myAnswer = document.getElementById("myAssumption").value; //getting user value

  if (myAnswer < actual) { //checking less tha answer
    alert("Guessed " + myAnswer + " too low");
    numberOfSteps++;
  } else if (myAnswer > actual) { //checking grater than answer
    alert("Guessed " + myAnswer + " too high");
    numberOfSteps++;
  } else { //you got answer
    alert("Guessed " + myAnswer + " Got it!!");
    alert("It tool " + numberOfSteps + " steps");
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see an array so what have you tried to store the value in an array?

Comment: no the array isnt there, i guess what im asking is how do i go about getting the random number stored until it is either guessed or the game ends

Comment: You're regenerating 'actual' on every checkMyAnswer() call. Move it out and you'll have a global actual, calculated once, which you can check against.

Comment: (smack myself on the forehead)...OMG i cant believe i dint see that...lol Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the jsfiddle. Check it out https://jsfiddle.net/e64gt4sv/3/.

```
var numberOfSteps = 1;
var actual = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
var guesses = [];

function checkMyAnswer() {
    ...
}
```

Jeremy is right, each time you call the checkMyAnswer, you regenerated the actual number. Instead, if you set it outside the function, you can still get the value inside the function, but it will only be set each time the actual javascript file loads (meaning each time the page is loaded / reloaded).

Also, I added something to store each guess in an array. The array `guesses` is a global variable, and then when you call checkMyAnswer(), the value that the user inputted is added to the array by doing

```
var myAnswer = document.getElementById("myAssumption").value; //getting user value
guesses.push(myAnswer);
```

Comment: Thanks...this helped alot

Comment: what if i wanted to have the computer guess the number?

Comment: you would keep the global variable actual outside the function, set the value of actual from inside the checkMyAnswer function (which you would probably rename) and then start the guessing algorithm